# Detect if parallel port exists

Tags: c#, parallel-port

I have a C# program that manipulates 2 wires using a variety of methods one of which is using a parallel port interface.

The user selects which method they would like to use and I would like to filter the options based on what is available on the machine.

I have been using [inpout32.dll](http://www.logix4u.net/index.php) for the parallel port communications but it gives no error if the computer has no parallel port so I need another way to tell.

I have seen numerous examples that look up the available printers to find the port, but no printer is connected so this solution will not work.

Comment: While there might be some method to detect if such a device exists on the system (as seen in Device Manager), there will be many system where this device exists (the circuitry and IO ports exist), but no actual physical port was soldered on to the motherboard (or there may be pins or some other internal connector into which you can connect a serial port that attaches to an expansion slot bracket). I don't see how you would be able to detect the presence of a physical DB-25 connector as opposed to unconnected leads, which would mean detection might not be possible in the general case.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek I've never a seen system with parallel port controller hardware without an actual port so determining if it is within device manager would be sufficient for me (this is internal software). I've seen what you are describing, but only for USB ports and audio devices, or on a SOC and not a PC.

Comment: My desktop computer came with a parallel port you had to plug in to the motherboard and attach to an available expansion slot bracket (I had no reason to). I've seen many computers and laptops where their chipset supported a parallel port (and appeared in Device Manager) but there was no physical port to be found (since it's basically extinct). I think it may be more common than you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can enumerate the devices via the WMI interface

here is an article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18268/How-To-Almost-Everything-In-WMI-via-C-Part-3-Hardw

there also exists a class called "Win32_ParallelPort: The Parallel ports"